# I want to display one by one value in JSP from spring controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

In my spring controller I have while loop which get new values everytime,I want to send new values to JSP from model attribute ,this is used for line chart

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getValuefromimag(final ModelMap model){
        Thread recordThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int cnt = 0;
                try {
                    int count=1;
                    while (cnt == 0 || record) {
                        ITesseract image = new Tesseract();   
                        image.setDatapath("C:/Users/hp/Documents/NetBeansProjects/DisplayVolume/dist/lib");
                        String str= image.doOCR(new File(store+"/"+count+".jpeg"));
                        MyDatas data =dSave(str);
                        model.addAttribute("sendData",data.getFirst());
                        if (cnt == 0) {
                            record = true;
                            cnt = 1;
                        }
                        count=count+1;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        recordThread.start();
        return "start";
    }                                                                                                    ...
```

Comment: are you send data to jsp page and print it in jsp pages ?

Comment: I have many images ,I extract text from from image then send it to JSP

Comment: What problem are you having doing this?

Comment: I have while loop which extract text from many images ,this while loop in inside separate thread , I'm only getting the last value after while loop finishes ,model.attribute("send",newvalues) is inside while loop .

Comment: Show your controller code for what you have done so far and jsp section where you want to show values.

Comment: @ajay kumar, I'm keeping changing my logics ,I can't show you the code now ,my question is ,can I send one by one value to jsp from controller ,there is while loop in controller method , recently I put (model.attribute) in while loop  , first when code enter the while loop ,it goes to jsp and never continue the loop , I want to continue looping ,tell me how

Comment: Doesn't matter what you have. If its there in the controller, it can be achieved.  Just show what you have tried and what didnt work. It will give a clear idea to everyone here what you are trying to achieve. I am sensing, you might have to use JavaScript in the mix. But without looking at bare minimum code the question will go in a infinite loop.

Comment: Please check the code

Comment: @ajay kumar , please check the code

Answer (score 0):

Quoting your comment: `I have while loop which extract text from many images ,this while loop in inside separate thread , I'm only getting the last value after while loop finishes ,model.attribute("send",newvalues) is inside while loop .`
That means your values are immediately being replaced by the new ones inside the loop as they hold the same variable name.
So, either  you need to store them in different variable or follow the below steps:

1. declare a list outside the loop
2. now, inside the loop, add values into the list
3. outside the loop, return the jstl page

This should work. Let me know if you face any difficulties doing this.

Answer (score -3):

I hope this will help you for achieve your goals.

**To use  the JSTL core tags in JSP pages by adding the following taglib directive:**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

**And to iterate list values, JSTL core have <c:forEach/> tag. It will display the list values one by one.**

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${empList}">
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

**Dependency Required**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

reference:
https://www.websparrow.org/spring/how-to-iterate-list-on-jsp-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I'm not sending list to JSP ,I have to send one by one values continuously from controller to JSP , please tell me how to achieve this, I'm using it for line chart

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30544847)

Comment: ok @Manohar i do this

Comment: @SathravaadaNagamani but instad of sanding one by one value, send list to jsp page and iterate inside jsp page

Comment: @batek's  ,if the method extract text from image then immediately I want to send to JSP because this new value is used to line chart,